# Растягивание div при помощи захвата мыши на javascript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте ! Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать возможность растягивания полей как это реализовано с полями для кода на http://jsfiddle.net/

т.е. я создаю div и нужна какая то функция с помощью которой можно изменять ширину или высоту захватом мыши, хотелось бы на чистом javascript

Comment: Вряд ли найдутся желающие реализовать специально для вас в рамках этого вопроса такую "функцию", тем более на чистом js. Максимум дело может ограничиться отправкой за [jquery](http://jquery.com)+[UI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/index.cfm). Если это задание в целях обучения, то начните сами, задавайте вопросы по ходу возникновения трудностей.

Comment: я уже в целом вроде разобрался, но все же есть некоторые глюки и застрял, нет идей как их исправить, можно к вам обратиться !? могу скинуть файлы

Comment: Если у вас возник конкретный вопрос, вы можете отредактировать этот вопрос, добавить описание проблемы. По конкретной проблеме любой желающий сможет вам помочь.